# What is this technique and why it is used for and how it works?

Tags: java, interface

I had recently asked question on stackoverflow, although I got the solution, but I am not able to understand the way the code is written there. This is the code

```
public class User {
@NotNull(message = "First name can't be blank", groups = {Step1.class, FinalStep.class})
private String firstName;

@NotNull(message = "Last name can't be blank", groups = {Step1.class, FinalStep.class})
private String lastName;

@NotNull(message = "Email can't be blank", groups = {Step1.class, FinalStep.class})
private String emailAddress;

@NotNull(message = "Please provide a valid address", groups = {Step2.class, FinalStep.class}) // this one also
private Address address;


public interface Step1 {} // this one 
public interface Step2 {}// this one 
public interface FinalStep {} // this one
}
```

the original post is [Link to original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738122/validating-wizard-pages-with-spring-3)

- The first question which comes in my mind why interface is declared in the class.
- Second what is the advantage of doing this type of coding
- and last where I can use this approach

Finally if it is useful, can you name this approach if not then any link which can explain about this more clearly.

Comment: If you don't have enough knowledge, then please don't down vote.

Comment: or atleast give a proper link or reason for down voting

Comment: It's a marker interface. These annotations enable validation. It's called [JSR-303 - Java Bean Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation). When you need to validate user input. In the future, I suggest asking one question - not three.

Comment: My downvote is because it it not clear what you  are asking.  (Not because I don't understand Java!)

Comment: What you have shown us is code not a "technique" or "approach".  If you want us to explain a specific "technique" or "approach" in that code, you need to explain which one you are talking about.  (Off the top of my head, I can quickly identify 4 possibilities ...)

Comment: Because I didn't knew the technique/approach name till now, and in the last three line, I had clearly mention what problem I was facing. Any way I got the solution.

Comment: And at last I even don't want any up voting just solution/help of my queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this searching SO:
[Why should we declare an interface inside a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648642/why-should-we-declare-an-interface-inside-a-class)

> Thus, when dealing with some hierarchy, you can describe a "nested"
>   interface, which will be implemented by the wrapping class's
>   subclasses.
>
> In the JDK, the most significant example would be Map.Entry inner
>   interface, defined within Map interface and implemented by various
>   ways by HashMap, LinkedHashMap etc...

Comment: @VivekSingh see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It may help with some of the downvotes.