# Spring MVC maintain the data in multiple form submissions

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I have a problem in where user will enter the data in first form and clicks on next. On next page user will enter few more data and clicks on next and on the 3rd page user will submit the data and it will get save into the database. I was using Struts 1.3 but there form data is not getting reset. But in Spring MVC form data is getting refreshed all the time in all the pages and all the data is not reaching to final submission. How to achieve this. I am using latest version of spring MVC i.e. 5.0.7.

Comment: I believe you are looking like an example of this: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/

Comment: I have seen this example. I am using fully annotation based. Is it mandatory to extend AbstractWizardFormController to work. If i extend this class can i use @Controller

Comment: Yes, still u can use annotations

Comment: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractWizardFormController This controller class it self is not exists in 5.0.7 release spring-webmvc.

Comment: Found the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623667/abstractwizardformcontroller-using-annotated-controllers